# What is 死す doing in this question?

Tags: verbs, register

My friend recently played through a game called Persona 4, and he took plenty of screen shots.  He showed me this one containing `死す`:

[image: Dialogue spoken by 巽 完二 「言っとくがなぁ… 可愛すぎてキュン死すっぞ！」]

It says:

> 巽　完二
>   「言っとくがなぁ…
>   　可愛すぎてキュン死すっぞ！」

I understood it as `死 + す`, a literary alternative to `死ぬ`.  I have to admit, though, it doesn't *sound* very literary to me in this context.  完二 is a tough guy, and he uses lots of verbal forms like `言っとく`, so I'm guessing I misunderstood.

**To sum up my question, I'm wondering why it was appropriate to say `死す` here.**

Comment: It looks to me to be キュン死 + すっぞ(=するぞ→すんぞ→すっぞ), キュン死 being a slang word meaning "death from a heart pang caused by seeing something cute". ("death by d'awwing"?) There's so much to this question that I doubt I could just post that and call it an answer, though. Not really sure what to do here.

Comment: @Hyperworm Ah, I was afraid I might have asked the wrong question due to my lack of understanding.  Maybe I should edit the question?

Comment: @Hyperworm I tried to pare it down so there isn't "so much to this question" anymore.  Sorry about that!

Comment: You had the right attitude approaching the question :D OK, since you've edited, I've tried to turn my comment into a better-formatted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than 死す (which I believe you are right in saying is literary), this is a slang suru-verb キュン死 meaning "death from a heart pang caused by seeing something cute".

(Possible English translations: "death by d'awwing", "death from cuteness overdose/overload"?)

The すっぞ comes from rough speech slurring -- するぞ→すんぞ→すっぞ -- so it fits his character.